# Dependency injection pattern needed inside service already built with DI framework

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I'm working on a project for work that has a lot of boilerplate.

The use-case is we have factories that produce a list of action objects that need to execute in sequence, and where the later actions might have references to the former ones.

So the factories are absolutely awful:

```
public class StepListCreator {
   private readonly _necessaryServiceFoo;
   private readonly _necessaryServiceBar;
   /* dozens more */
   public StepListCreator( /* all the above injected */ ) { /* ... */ }

   public List<IStep> Create(Dictionary<string, object> request) {
     var step1 = new InitializeStep(request['init'], _necessaryServiceBar);
     var step2 = new ProcessingStep(request['proc'], step1, _necessaryServiceFoo);
     /* many more */
     return new List<IStep> { step1, step2, /* ... */ }
   }
}
```

The obvious solution *would* be to just register everything scoped with `IServiceCollection` and be done with it, but...

The problem is that each of the steps also implement various other interfaces, so the `InitializeStep` might be a `IAuthenticationProvider` or something, which is what `ProcessingStep` needs it for, and we have multiple such `IAuthenticationProvider`s in the same program.

The idea I have is to somehow make a tiny service collection that piggy-backs off the `ServiceProvider` used to resolve the `StepListCreator` and then registers an `InitializeStep` and so on, so the responsibility of the `StepListCreator` is only to know the ordering of the actions, and not include a bunch of code about passing around arguments.

It seems like we have the perfect case for using a kind of dependency injection framework, but I need it to be localized in some sense.

Comment: Where does the `Dictionary<string, object> request` comes from ? Is it from the HttpContext ?

Comment: @ArwynFr It's a stand-in for a more complex request object, which is sent as JSON through a message queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I have come up with is to use a simple reflection-based depdendency resolution algorithm that builds a list of instantiated services, and for each subsequent service iterates backwards over that list looking for applicable candidates for dependency resolution before resorting to an service provider. It comes out to about 70 lines of logic code, and 80-ish lines of miscellaneous classes.

The only refactoring needed is to eliminate the passing of concrete data as arguments to the step constructors. Everything is now passed as a provider interface, and the request object argument to the entire process is wrapped in a parser class that implements several such provider interfaces.

This modest investment has resulted in an >90% reduction in code size.

I can't post the code, obviously, as it is proprietary, but the algorithm in pseudocode is:

- GenerateServices(Type[] servicelist, object[] arguments):
- Have an output list of instantiated services.
- For each service in the service list, resolve it and add to the output list.
- To instantiate a service, resolve each of the the dependencies of its constructor as follows:
- Iterate backwards over the output list and look for a resolution candidate.
- Then look through the arguments.
- Then check if the output list is perhaps applicable as a resolution candidate.
- Only then resort to the external service provider.

Answer (score -1):

Note: injection constructors are redacted in all examples below.

##### Using an injection accessor

You can register a non-transient accessor that holds the dictionary for you:

```cs
public class ItemsAccessor
{
  public IDictionary<string, object> Items { get; init; }
}
```

`StepListCreator` may `.AddRange()` values or the `ItemsAccessor` class can intialize the data for you depending on how you get values from your context. Then you can delegate creation of the steps to the DI library, and even cast the value to the correct type:

```cs
public class ProcessingStep : IStep
{
  private readonly ItemsAccessor _itemsAccessor;
  private readonly IServiceBar _necessaryServiceBar;
  private readonly IStep _initializeStep;

  private TValue Item => _itemsAccessor.Items['init'] as TValue;
}
```

You can also take advantage of injecting the `IServiceProvider` to prevent constructor parameters overload:

```cs
public class StepListCreator
{
  private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

  private static readonly Type[] _stepTypes = {
      typeof(InitializeStep),
      typeof(ProcessingStep),
      // ...
  };

  public List<IStep> Create() => _stepTypes
    .Select(type => _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService(type) as IStep)
    .ToList();
}
```

##### Using IHttpContextAccessor

If data comes from the `HttpContext`, you should use `IHttpContextAccessor`:

```cs
public class ProcessingStep : IStep
{
  private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
  private readonly IServiceFoo _necessaryServiceFoo;
  private readonly IStep _initializeStep;

  private HttpRequest Request => _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request;
  private object Item => Request.RouteValues['proc'];
}
```

However, if you are trying to have a series of classes that handles an HttpRequest in sequence, [you're probably looking for Middlewares](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

##### Using property injector

If you really need to populate the dictionary at resolve-time, consider injecting values using properties injection instead of constructor:

```cs
public class StepListCreator
{
  private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

  public List<IStep> Create(IDictionary<string, object> request)
  {
    var step1 = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<InitializeStep>() as IStep;
    step1.Item = request['init'];

    var step2 = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ProcessingStep>() as IStep;
    step1.Item = request['proc'];

    //...

    return { step1, step2 }.ToList();
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you have a LOT of technical debt. The fact that these steps implement other interfaces and do more than specify exactly what a specific part of the process should do, tells me that the classes are probably violating the single responsibility principle.

If it were me, I would be advocating to refactor this code and separate out the ordering of commands from the performing of the commands. The objects that do the commands should be sort of throw-away rather than being the same objects that actually implement the nitty gritty of the behavior. Their "one job" is just to act as the object that performs a specific task on provided dependencies. The fact that you have to pass former steps to latter steps tells me that your service objects are doing double-duty as both the performer of the action and the command itself to do the action.

It might seem confusing that the command to do an action isn't the action itself because at first it seems like an unnecessary layer of indirection, but this is exactly the kind of problem that SOLID is meant to solve: inflexibility in software design because of tight coupling, and there's no tighter coupling than two objects or two responsibilities fused into a single inflexible object.

Essentially, when you've refactored, it should look something like this:

```cs
public interface IService {
    /* ... */
}

public class InitializationService : IService { /* ... */ }
public class ProcessService : IService { /* ... */ }
public class CleanupService : IService { /* ... */ }


public interface IStep {
    public void perform();
    public IService service { get; set; };
    public IStep(IService service);
}

public class InitializationStep : IStep {
    public InitializationStep(IService initService) { /* ... */ }
    public perform() { /* ... */ }
    public IService service { get; set; };
}
/* Do the same for the other steps */


public class StepListCreator {
    private List<IStep> initList;
    private List<IStep> proc;
    private List<IStep> cleanup;
    
    public StepListCreator (List<IStep> initList, List<IStep> procList, List<IStep> cleanupList) { /* ... */ }
    
    public List<IStep> Create() {
        List<IStep> result = new List<IStep>();
        
        result.join(init);
        result.join(proc);
        result.join(cleanup);
        
        return result;
    }
}
```

This is how you use it:

```cs
var init = new InitializationService(request['init']);
var proc = new ProcessingService(request['proc'], init);
var cleanup = new CleanupService(request['cleanup'], init);

var factory = new StepListCreator(
    new List<IStep>() {
        new InitializationStep(init)
    },
    new List<IStep>() {
        new ProcessStep(proc)
    },
    new List<IStep>() {
        new CleanupStep(cleanup)
    }
);

var list = factory.Create();
```

And when you're ready to execute the whole process...

```cs
foreach (var i in list) { i.perform(); }
```

Comment: "It sounds like you have a LOT of technical debt." We don't, actually. The problem we're solving has significant innate complexity, and this boilerplate code is easy to both understand, write, and maintain. The broader system is highly modular and regular. The problem I am trying to resolve is code volume.